# jQuery image slideshow - last slide appearing without moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I have created a simple image slider in jQuery, sliding is working fine I have trying to do the two things:

1. instead of margin-left (in sliding) I want to use `transform:translate3d` so it has smoothness
2. When the third slide is complete, first slide show without sliding animation (appearing with jerkness)

Can somebody please give me idea on this?

Here is [working JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/kun483zc/)

```js
'use strict';
$(document).ready(function() {

  var winw = $(window).width();
  var winh = $(window).height();

  // variables
  var width = $(window).width();
  var timeFrame = 4000;
  var pause = 8000;
  var currentSlide = 1;

  // cache dom
  var $slider = $('#slider');
  var $slideContainer = $('.slides', $slider);
  var $slides = $('.slide', $slider);
  var interval;

  // functions
  function startSlider() {
    interval = setInterval(function() {
      //translate3d(x, y, z)
      $slideContainer.animate({
        'margin-left': '-=' + width
      }, timeFrame, function() {

        if (++currentSlide === $slides.length) {
          currentSlide = 1;
          $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
        }
      });
    }, pause);
  }

  function pauseSlider() {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }

  // call functions
  //$slideContainer.on('mouseenter', pauseSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);
  startSlider();

  $("#slider .slide").height(winh);
  $("#slider .slide").width(winw);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  background: #eee;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#slider .slides {
  display: block;
  width: 10000px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#slider .slide {
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 1050px;
}

.slide1 {
  background: url(imgs/slide-image-1.jpg) no-repeat center;
}

.slide2 {
  background: url(imgs/slide-image-2.jpg)no-repeat center;
}

.slide3 {
  background: url(imgs/slide-image-3.jpg)no-repeat center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li class="slide slide1"></li>
    <li class="slide slide2"></li>
    <li class="slide slide3"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `startSlider` function and need to change `margin-left` using `animate`.

```
   function startSlider() {
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            //translate3d(x, y, z)
            $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '-='+width}, timeFrame, function() {
                if (++currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                     currentSlide = 1;
                     //$slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
                     $slideContainer.animate({'margin-left': '0'});
                }
            });
        }, pause);
    }
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/kun483zc/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Manoj but unfortunately its not working as expected, what I am trying to achieve is when the third and last slide is done, the first slide should move the same..continues keep sliding..